# Getting means of two variables based on one column and grouped by another

Tags: r

I have this data frame.

[image]

Subjects include 1-5 with a count of 30 for each. Intervals 1-30 and X and Y coordinates for each interval and subject.
I want to have the intervals binned into groups of 6 in order to get the means of X and Y per bin for each subject.

`subset <- mydata %>% group_by(Subject) %>% summarise_at(vars(X:Y), mean, na.rm = TRUE)`

When I do this, I get the overall means of X and Y for all intervals. How would I go about doing this correctly?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  may help.

Comment: you can use `dput(your_dataframe)` in order to print a reproducible example of your dataframe in R in the form of code.

Comment: Please also see [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).